# Is it normal that Software installs in Admin user folder?

Tags: windows-7, installation

I've got a new computer with Windows 7, which I'm using for the first time. For security I decided to create a standard user for everyday work instead of using an admin account.

However when I install programs logged in as the standard user (such as Aptana right now) they always try to install in the admin's user folder (C:\Users\Admin\AppData...). I'd expect the programs to install to the standard user's folder or Progran Files as in XP. This also leads to that I need to grant admin rights whenever I start such a program.

Of course I could just change the installation path every time, but I find this behavior strange. Ist it normal, or did I somehow mess up the Windows 7 installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some older programs don't play well with Windows Vista and Windows 7, and you have to right click and select run as administrator for these insallers.  If you install the program using the login credentials of an admin account all of the variables such as %temp% %systemroot$, etc. will be localized to that account.  This is assuming you install programs by granting them admin privileges associated with another account.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm running the installation as the standard user but it's still being installed in the admin's folder instead of the standard user's folder. Otherwise the installation and the running later seem to be fine.

Comment: Well, I guess to answer your original question:  No. It is not usual for Windows 7 to install to that location.  All I can suggest is to try to repair your windows 7 installation.